# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken for minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, minitest, database-cleaner

I get the following error when running `rake test`:

```
Error:
ShareTest#test_valid_setup:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
test/models/share_test.rb:7:in `setup'
```

Why? I'm really not sure what this means, because I get the error even when I override the `email` parameter in my setup. My other tests pass just fine. My model associations are written so that:

-`User` has_many `Items`, `Trades`, and `Shares`

-`Trade` belongs_to `User` and `Share`

-`Share` belongs_to `User` and `Item`

-`Item` belongs_to `User` and has_many `Trades` and `Shares`

The related factories are:

```
FactoryBot.define do
 factory :user, aliases: [:owner, :trade_requester, :trade_recipient, :share_owner] do
  email Faker::Internet.email
  firstname Faker::Name.first_name
  lastname Faker::Name.last_name
  username Faker::Pokemon.name
  website Faker::Internet.domain_name
 end

 factory :item do
  owner
  image { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('test', 'lilac.jpg'), 'image/jpeg') }
  title Faker::Book.title
  artist Faker::Book.author
  medium Faker::Book.genre
  year Faker::Number.number(4)
  price Faker::Number.between(1, 5)
  length Faker::Number.between(1, 2)
  height Faker::Number.between(1, 2)
  width Faker::Number.between(1, 2)
  agreement true
 end

 factory :share, aliases: [:wanted_share, :collateral_share] do
  user
  item
  amount { Item.price }
  active true
 end
end
```

And then the actual test where I'm getting the duplicate email error is:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'support/database_cleaner'

class ShareTest < Minitest::Test
 def setup
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  @share = FactoryBot.create(:share)
 end

 def test_valid_setup
  assert_kind_of Integer, share.amount
 end

 def teardown
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
 end
end
```

Comment: What does `Faker::Internet.email` return? Is it always the same?
I'm guessing there is a unique constraint on the `email` attribute for a user. When you create a `:share` with factory bot, it's creating an associated user, then an associated item, which also has a user associated with it. So it's going to try to create two users with the same email.

Comment: this is a dumb question, but how do i see what `Faker::whatever` returns? I'm just setting up my tests and running them with `rake test`. and how would i go about *using* existing users and items instead of creating them for each factory?

Comment: You should be able to create each of them individually and override them in the factory `create` method. `test_user = create :user` then `test_item = create :item, user: test_user`, and finally `create :share, item: test_item, user: test_user`

Comment: Also, using `Faker::Internet.unique.email` might work too. But I don't know much about that gem.

Comment: Ugh, testing is so confusing. That worked. If you write your response up as an answer I can give u credit. Thank so  much!